# Asynchronous Training of Deep Learning Models

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, graph-neural-network

I am thinking of how would it be if I can create asynchronous **forward** function in sub-class of nn.Module . When I came across architecture in attached image, I felt that it would be faster if we could train pass through each branch parallelly.

[image]

Another scenario I have come across is when input is of shape (B, C ,V ,T) , where :
`B: batch_sz , C: node_features , V : num_nodes , T : time_stamps`
So, there is a graph for each time-stamp corresponding to each instance in the batch. Now there is a module which calculates Adj_matrix of a graph based on its node_features... It would be compute intensive if we club (B,C,V,T)->(BxT, C,V) , and then treat (B*T) as new batch , where T~=250 , B=32....

Is there some work-around that we can  evaluate adj_mat efficiently... This problem is not only limited to calculation of adj_mat through my custom module, but rather to use any graph layer from PyG, we need to club B,T

**I'm not talking about training on multiple GPU, but making calls asynchronously rather than sequentially.**

Please answer both the question , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, CUDA computations (i.e. kernels) are asynchronous (see [the CUDA docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html) and [the Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#asynchronous-execution)). Therefore, what you suggested is already happening under the hoods.

Comment: Thanks bro, I didn't know about it... The way I write forward function made me felt that things are done synchronously... I mean I don't write async anywhere .... Btw I would go through the resources you provided....